# What is this Buefy (Vue + Bulma) function doing here?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, buefy

I am new to Buefy and fairly new to Vue.  The Buefy documentation on forms has an example autocomplete [here](https://buefy.org/documentation/autocomplete) which referenced a computed property on the data field.  I think the function is taking the name input and then filtering the data array accordingly.

The bit I am not sure of are the mechanics of how it's actually working i.e. why there are two return statements, where are 'options' coming from why is the lowercase method in there...

```
<template>
    <section>
        <p class="content"><b>Selected:</b> {{ selected }}</p>
        <b-field label="Find a JS framework">
            <b-autocomplete
                rounded
                v-model="name"
                :data="filteredDataArray"
                placeholder="e.g. jQuery"
                icon="magnify"
                clearable
                @select="option => selected = option">
                <template slot="empty">No results found</template>
            </b-autocomplete>
        </b-field>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: [
                    'Angular',
                    'Angular 2',
                    'Aurelia',
                    'Backbone',
                    'Ember',
                    'jQuery',
                    'Meteor',
                    'Node.js',
                    'Polymer',
                    'React',
                    'RxJS',
                    'Vue.js'
                ],
                name: '',
                selected: null
            }
        },
        computed: {
            filteredDataArray() {
                return this.data.filter((option) => {
                    return option
                        .toString()
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .indexOf(this.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: these questions are related to javascript and especially to ecmascript 6, check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Comment: To explain the option(s) and double return you have to dive into arrow functions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The toLowerCase is just to make your search query a bit smarter, so both 'rxjs' and 'RXJS' return 'RxJS'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ES6 question, so in order to understand the answer you need to understand `.filter()`. [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

What happens is basic **functional programming** in JS. I'd suggest you to have some reading about it.

So `this.data` is an array and `.filter()` is a
method of JS that iterates among array items, and returns the matching option(s).

So basically `.filter()` returns an array of the matching values, and then the second return, is returning the array coming out from the filter **to where the function ( `filteredDataArray()` ) was called from.**